# How to get element with its style attribute in protractor?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, protractor

i am new to use protractor. There is an html element which its only unique part is url of background image in style attribute. You can see below.

```
<div _ngcontent-jaf-c293="" class="ng-star-inserted" style="background-image: 
url(&quot;/assets/map-markers/vms-marker.png&quot;); background-repeat: no-repeat; 
background-size: 100% 100%; height: 44.1px; width: 27.5625px;"></div>
```

I tried to get this element.(see below)

```
 var created = element(by.xpath('//div[contains(@style,"background-image: url(\"/assets/map-markers/vms-marker.png\");")]'));
```

I am gettting syntax error. How to write expression to get this element? Or is it possible to get element with the style attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

var marker = element(by.xpath("//div[@style[contains(.,'vms-marker.png')]]")); worked

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).